# Two questions about my .getStuff method and OO programming in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

The following block of code contains a series of functions that cover object orientated programming within Javascript. Its based on the third video tutorial by Youtuber, Derek Banas.

He never quite finished his .getStuff method, but I've been attempting to do it with method overloading as well as a switch statement.

Obviously, the print statements after it are not being executed so there appears to be something wrong. What is wrong with my code?

Also, I have a general question, how could I use object orientated programming on a band website? These ideas are fine for games, but I don't see the use in a general website (I've learned OO programming for Pygame so far and it makes total sense for a game setting, but idk the uses in a website).

**Here is my code, skip to the bottom for the .getStuff method:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title> Tutorial 3 (Object Orientated Programming) </title>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8"/>

        <script>

            // This tutorial will cover OO based programming

            // Object: Stores variables and the functions to manipulate these variables in one place

            // Class: This is the blueprint that defines what variables and functions each object will
            // have

            // Property: Names given to variables stored inside of objects

            // Methods: Name given to functions that are part of an object

            // The following example will create an Animal object

            // This is also called a constructor since it is a function that is designed to
            // create (construct) a new object

            function Animal()
            {
                // Define all the properties that you want the Animal object to contain:

                // this: "This" is a reference to object that you create

                this.name = "No Name";
                this.sound = "Grrr";
                this.owner = "No Owner";

            }

            // The following will create a prototype for a method that can be used by the Animal
            // object

            // Format is: nameOfObject.prototype.setOwner: this sets the value for the variable

            // function(property that the function will accept)


            // Encapsulation: Grouping of properties and their methods needed to manipulate 
            // those properties

            Animal.prototype.setOwner = function(newOwner)
            {
                // The following checks if a newOwner value has been passed
                if(typeof newOwner != 'undefined')
                {
                    // You now want the value of owner to be the value of owner that has been
                    // passed to it as a parameter:
                    this.owner = newOwner;


                }

                else
                {
                    document.write("Please enter a valid owner." + "</br>");

                }


            }

            // This function will return whatever the name of the current owner is
            Animal.prototype.getOwner = function()
            {

                return this.owner;

            }

            // Set the name of the animal using the previous method:
            Animal.prototype.setName = function(newName)
            {
                if(typeof newName != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.name = newName;


                }

                else
                {
                    document.write("Please enter a valid name." + "</br>");

                }



            }

            Animal.prototype.getName = function()
            {
                return this.name;

            }

            // Set the sound for the object:
            Animal.prototype.setSound = function(newSound)
            {
                if(typeof newSound != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.sound = newSound;


                }

                else
                {

                    document.write("Please enter a valid sound." + "</br>");

                }



            }

            Animal.prototype.getSound = function()
            {

                return this.sound;



            }


            // The following will literally create new Animal objects and probably call these
            // function prototypes by passing in parameters for sound, name, and owner

            var dog = new Animal();

            // ^ This object has now been created and contains the defaults for sound, name, and owner
            // according to the original function

            // Now we are going to set the properties individually:

            dog.setName("Cheyenne");
            dog.setSound("Bark!");
            dog.setOwner("Sam");

            // Now, finally use the get versions of the functions by simply calling them via a document.write

            document.write("The name of the dog is: " + dog.getName() + "</br>");
            document.write("The sound of the dog is: " + dog.getSound() + "</br>");
            document.write("The owner of the dog is: " + dog.getOwner() + "</br>");


            // My small goal:
            // Make a cat object instead:
            var cat = new Animal();

            cat.setName("Mr. Buttons")
            cat.setSound("Purrrr")
            cat.setOwner("Crazy Cat Lady")

            // Print the results to screen:
            document.write("The name of cat is: " + cat.getName() + "</br>");
            document.write("The sound of the cat is: " + cat.getSound() + "</br>");
            document.write("The owner of the cat is: " + cat.getOwner() + "</br>");

            function Cat()
            {
                // The following will "inherit" all the attributes of the Animal class:
                // This is a reference to the next cat object that you create.

                // This forces the animal constructor to be called

                Animal.call(this)
                this.mood = "Crazy";

            }

            // Superclass: the class you want your new class to inherit from

            // Without the following statement, Cat would become a subclass instead

            Cat.prototype = new Animal();

            // Here we are making the constructor be of type Cat
            Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat();

            // Create a getMood method:

            Cat.prototype.getMood = function()
            {
                return this.mood;

            }

            // Create a setMOood method where the user passed in a mood as a parameter:
            Cat.prototype.setMood = function(newMood)
            {
                if(typeof newMood != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.mood = newMood;

                }

                else
                {
                    document.write("Please enter a valid mood!</br>");


                }


            }

            // Make a new Panda object:

            function Panda()
            {
                Animal.call(this);

                this.mood = "Calm";


            }

            Panda.prototype = new Animal();


            Panda.prototype.constructor = Panda();


            // Get Mood:
            Panda.prototype.getMood = function()
            {
                return this.mood;


            }

            // Set Mood:
            Panda.prototype.setMood = function(newMood)
            {
                if(typeof newMood != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.mood = newMood;

                }

                else
                {
                    document.write("Please enter a valid mood!</br>");


                }


            }

            myPanda = new Panda();

            myPanda.setMood("Excited");

            document.write("myPanda's mood is: " + myPanda.getMood() + "</br>");

            theGreatOne = new Panda();

            theGreatOne.setMood("Courageous");

            document.write("theGreatOne's mood is: " + theGreatOne.getMood() + "</br>");



            // The following will determine if myPanda is an INSTANCE of the Panda class or
            // an actual Panda object:

            document.write("Is myPanda an instance of the Panda class?: " + (myPanda instanceof Panda) + "</br>");



            // The following will use "typeof" to determine the data type of the myPanda object
            // and the Panda class

            // As seen by the example, classes are classified as functions in Javascripts

            document.write("What is the data type of myPanda?: " + (typeof myPanda) + "</br>");

            document.write("What is the data type of Panda?: " + (typeof Panda) + "</br>");



            // Method Overloading: Creating multiple different versions or methods that all
            // have a different number of attributes

            // Aka, a different version of a method will be called depending on how many
            // arguments are passed to the function

            setStuff(newName);

            setStuff(newName, newSound);

            setStuff(newName, newSound, newOwner);

            Panda.prototype.setStuff = function(newName, newSound, newOwner)
            {
                if((typeof newName != 'undefined') && (typeof newSound != 'undefined') && (typeof newOwner != 'undefined'))
                {
                    Panda.prototype.setStuff = function(newName, newSound, newOwner)
                    {



                        switch(arguments.length)
                        {

                            case 3:
                                this.owner = newOwner;

                            case 2:
                                this.sound = newSound;

                            case 1: 
                                this.name = newName;
                        }

                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    document.write("Please enter a valid name</br>");

                }




            }

            newPanda.setStuff("Jiggly");

            document.write("myPanda's new name is: " + myPanda.getName() + "</br>");

            // ^ Work on fixing this


            // Continue at 15:51

            // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVnW7ZMqBus


            // Polymorphism:

            // doAnimalStuff(Animal){ document.write(Animal.getName() + Animal.getOwner()) };


        </script>

        <noscript>


        </noscript>


    </head>

    <body>
        <p> This is a sample paragraph </p>








    </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Cat.prototype = new Animal();
> ```

[Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572). Better:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

---

> ```
> document.write("The name of cat is: " + cat.getName() + "</br>");
> ```

[Try not to use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572). For example scripts like this, use `console.log` instead.

---

> ```
> // Method Overloading: Creating multiple different versions or methods that all
> // have a different number of attributes
>
> // Aka, a different version of a method will be called depending on how many
> // arguments are passed to the function
>
> setStuff(newName);
> setStuff(newName, newSound);
> setStuff(newName, newSound, newOwner);
> ```

These three lines should probably go in the comment as well. There is no `setStuff` function defined anywhere, so trying to call it will throw an error and halt the script execution. Check your error console. Better:

```
// setStuff(newName);
// setStuff(newName, newSound);
// setStuff(newName, newSound, newOwner);
```

---

> ```
> Cat.prototype.setMood = function(newMood) {
>     …
>     document.write("Please enter a valid mood!</br>");
> }
> ```

OOP tip: Try not to do user interaction in setter methods. This is too specific and does assume a) that the *user* called the method (not the programmer) b) that the user *entered* something somewhere c) that the preferred output method for this kind of error is `document.write`. Not of that might be true.

Instead, do a `throw new Error("not a valid mood")` or so. Catch it in the UI code if it is something that can be entered by a user, and do the error message output there as well. It does not have anything to do with cats.

---

> ```
> Panda.prototype.setStuff = function(newName, newSound, newOwner) {
>     if((typeof newName != 'undefined') && (typeof newSound != 'undefined') && (typeof newOwner != 'undefined')) {
>         Panda.prototype.setStuff = function(newName, newSound, newOwner) {
> ```

Uh, what? Declare (assign) the method only once! I didn't exactly check, but it seems likely that there also is a syntax error at the closing braces.

---

> ```
> Cat.prototype.getMood = …
> Cat.prototype.setMood = …
> Panda.prototype.getMood = …
> Panda.prototype.setMood = …
> ```

[Don't repeat yourself!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) Possible OOP solutions would include here:

- define moods on the `Animal` class
- introduce a new subclass `AnimalWithMood` is only some animals can have a mood
- use the mixin pattern if you would like arbitrary classes to have moods

---

> ```
> switch(arguments.length) {
>     case 3:
>         this.owner = newOwner;
>     case 2:
>         this.sound = newSound;
>     case 1: 
>         this.name = newName;
> }
> ```

Interesting use of a fall-through. However, what would happen in case of 4 arguments passed, should they be ignored then?

An [explicit check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694605/1048572) would be better:

```
if (arguments.length >= 3)
    this.owner = newOwner;
if (arguments.length >= 2)
    this.sound = newSound;
if (arguments.length >= 1)
    // do validity checks in this block!
    this.name = newName;
```

OOP tip: God methods like this `setStuff` are despised - you see it at the method name including "stuff" already. Consider a more fluent interface with method chaining, or objects as parameters.

---

> I have a general question, how could I use object orientated programming on a band website?

Much too general. OOP is a programming paradigm, and has nothing to do with the *functionality* of the code. Also, "a XY website" usually does not need any kind of programming anyway. Be more specific what interactive/dynamic stuff you want to see on your page.

Comment: +1, except for one thing: don't comment out code, remove it. Great answer, though!

Comment: @IngoBürk: You mean the `setStuff` invocation examples? Yeah, they might be superfluous, but I thought they were part of the literate-programming style of the tutorial.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that. Either way, I enjoyed reading the answer since you pointed out many helpful things for the OP.

Comment: Obviously, I'm not that great at OO programming. What is a good resource for Javascript in general because obviously I've been learning through videos, and I didn't even know that document.write was outdated heh. I want my site to become interactive so it was nice to do some scripts in Javascript so far, but I would like to know more graphical UI based material using Javascript and HTML

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html is a good start to learn the language. For UI, you a) need to study design b) learn to use libraries