# Variable number of arguments in a function

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Is it possible to tell a function what names it should give to its arguments, based on the number of arguments passed? Like this:

```
function soSwag(swagLevel, swagStart, swagDuration || swagStart, swagStop){}
```

Comment: No, however you can use the length of `arguments` to decide how to use said arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [method overloading in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694588/method-overloading-in-javascript)

Comment: This would be a good opportunity for a small open-source library that implements var args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What some popular libraries (e.g. jQuery) that support variable types of arguments do is that they examine the arguments and then swap values accordingly:

```
function soSwag(swagLevel, swagStart, swagDuration) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        var swagStop = swagStart;   // 2nd arg becomes swagStop
        swagStart = swagLevel;      // first arg becomes swagStart

        // code here that uses swagStart and swagStop
        // as called like soSwag(swagStart, swagStop)

    } else {

        // code here that uses swagLevel, swagStart, swagDuration
        // as called like soSwag(swagLevel, swagStart, swagDuration)

    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Do i have to check with `===` or am i good with just `==`?

Comment: `===` is a better overall javascript habit to get into (because it avoids implicit type conversions which you usually do not want), though either `===` or `==` will work here.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge. However, you can just pass in an object with the data you want.

```
soSwag({
    swagStart: 10,
    swagStop: 100
});
```

However, it might be cleaner to simply pass `null` into that first parameter.