# How to add extra parameter when changing anonymous function to named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I have a situation like this:

```
"render": function(a, b) { // do stuff }
```

I want to change this to a named function:

```
"render": foo

function foo(a, b) { // do stuff }
```

The thing is, the function can do different things in different situations, so I want to add another parameter like this:

```
function foo(a, b, type)
```

How do I call this function and still pass in the original parameters? I have no control over the code that calls this method so I don't know where `a` and `b` come from.

Comment: So what is the issue? You want to call the original function? If they do not pass in type it is undefined... `if (type===undefined){ console.log("no type"); }`

Comment: You can just call it `foo(x, y)` regardless how many parameters the function has (`type` would be `undefined` then). What does not work? Are you looking for [method overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694605/1048572)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (typeof type === 'undefined') {
    // 2 parameters
} else {
    // 3 parameters
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify, `a` and `b` are parameters that I don't pass in by myself, they are passed into the function by the framework. I want to add an additional 'type' parameter that I pass in myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for `type` in the function

```
"render": function(a, b,type) {
 if(type !== undefined){
      //do stuff with type
   } 
 // do stuff 
 }
```

Comment: Let me clarify, `a` and `b` are parameters that I don't pass in by myself, they are passed into the function by the framework. I want to add an additional 'type' parameter that I pass in myself.